# VBA: convert specific formula to values

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a VBA to convert all instances of the offset formula in a sheet to values. However, the code only changes the original cell where the offset function is in and not the whole array that is affected by the offset function. How do I change the code so that it replaces the whole spilled array?

```
Sub SearchFormula()
Dim mySearch()
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Range
mySearch = Array("OFFSET")
For i = 0 To UBound(mySearch)
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    Set c = .Find(mySearch(i), LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    Do
        c.Value = c.Value
        Set c = .FindNext(c)
    Loop Until c Is Nothing
End With
Next i
    
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the formula?

Comment: What to convert "offset formula in a sheet to values" should mean? If the formula contains "OFFSET(H3,0,-2)" to extract "F3"? To extract the value of "F3"? Can there be more than one Offset in a formula? How to be returned all findings? Do you simple need to evaluate formula and place in the cell the formula result, as your code tries doing? What "whole array that is affected by the offset function" does mean? Without showing us the formula and the desired result, I am afraid, nobody can help you...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't examined the `.SpillingToRange` property much, but the following sequence seems to work for replacing the Spilled from the formula with the actual values.

You may need to test first that the range is a spilled range.
Code below assumes you have already found the cell `c` with the `OFFSET` formula:

```
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    
Select Case c.HasSpill
    Case True
        v = c.SpillingToRange
        Set r2 = c.SpillingToRange
        r2 = v
    Case False
        c.Value = c.Value
End Select
```